# how to reverse the order of words in query or c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

i have stored in the database as

location

India,Tamilnadu,Chennai,Annanagar

while i bind in the grid view it ll be displaying as 
'India,Tamilnadu,Chennai,Annanagar' this format.

but i need to be displayed as 'Annanagar,Chennai,Tamilnadu,India' in this format. how to perform this reverse order in query or in c#

note: this is stored under one column as 'India,Tamilnadu,Chennai,Annanagar' with comma separated.

Comment: but this is not stored seperately to give as orderby. it is stored jointly as  'India,Tamilnadu,Chennai,Annanagar' in one column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe location example provided by OP is just one result from DB and he is looking for something like this:

```
string location = "India,Tamilnadu,Chennai,Annanagar";
string[] words = location.Split(',');

Array.Reverse(words);

string newlocation = String.Join(",", words);

Console.WriteLine(newlocation); // Annanagar,Chennai,Tamilnadu,India
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT location FROM locations ORDER BY location ASC // server side sorting
```

Or if you have your result in a DataTable you could use this:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "location ASC"; // client side in-memory sorting
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you could use the order by query.

```
SELECT * FROM location
ORDER BY City
```

This will return the results ordered alphabetically by the City column.

If you wanted to reverse the order so it would be ordered from Z -> A you would do

```
ORDER BY City DESC
```

It is generally always a good idea to apply some kind of ordering in your queries that will be used for display, otherwise the results come back in a random non-deterministic order which is rarely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using C# we have:

```
var arr = new[] { "India", "Tamilnadu", "Chennai", "Annanagar" };
```

Using LINQ:

```
var q = from location in arr
        orderby location ascending // or descending
        select location;
```

Using extension methods:

```
var q = arr.OrderBy(l => l);
var q = arr.OrderByDescending(l => l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to make the string Locality,City,State,Country when you have it stored in the reverse order? then you cant do that using sorting.

If you have all the values stored in a single field as comma separated values, In C#, you can split the string by Comma as the separator and then join it again by appending the items in the reverse order by using comma as separator.