# How do I reverse the numbers in a string?

Tags: java, string, reverse

For example, if I have a string that contains 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, how do i make it so that a new string or how to print out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? Thanks.

Comment: Read from one end of the source and write to the opposite end of the target.

Comment: There is no function built into the Java API; you will need to create your own method, in which case it would be good if you included your question anything you've tried.

Comment: click on one of the related links on the right, you will see the solution.

Comment: If you were learning java don't use built in functionality or else you can't enjoy coding.

Answer (score 2):

do something like that:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("3, 2, 1");

 System.out.println(builder.reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a built-in method, this is the shortest solution:

```
String input = "12345";
String output = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
```

If you need to implement your own solution, this is an efficient answer using a `char[]` and iterating over just half of the input string:

```
String input = "12345";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, n = chars.length; i < n/2; i++) {
    char tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[n-i-1];
    chars[n-i-1] = tmp;
}
String output = new String(chars);
```

Either way, the input will be reversed:

```
System.out.println(output);
> 54321
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert String into Character array. Loop from characterarray's length -1 to 0 index printing each character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096845/adding-comma-separated-strings-to-an-arraylist-and-visa-versa) question about parsing comma delimited strings to arrays. Reverse the array and then see the same question about turning the array back into a comma delimited string.

Also you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988699/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-words-in-query-or-c-sharp) c# code as an example which should be easy to port.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in reversing the `String`, with out caring about the natural order, you could do something like

```
String word = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
word = word.replace(", ", "");

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1);
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        s.append(", ");
    }
    s.append(c);
}
```

Which outputs `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Now of course, if you're interested in maintaining the natural order of the numbers, it becomes a little more complicated...

```
//String value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
String value = "1, 5, 4, 3, 2";
System.out.println("Start with " + value);
String parts[] = value.split(", ");

// We need to convert the String values to ints
List<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
for (String part : parts) {
    listOfValues.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
}
// Allow the API to sort them...
Collections.sort(listOfValues);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());
for (Integer part : listOfValues) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(part);
}

System.out.println(sb);


System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Which outputs

```
Start with 1, 5, 4, 3, 2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it:

```
String values = "5, 4, 3, 2, 1";
values = values.replace(", ", " ,");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values);
values = sb.reverse().toString();
System.out.println(values);
```

Output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```